# wrapping text in flexbox

Tags: css, flexbox

is it possible to wrap text in flex within a fixed width container?

so it looks like

```
img username added
    you as a friend
```

rather than

```
    user added
img name you as
         a
         friend
```

I can do this if the image and a were separate, but since they both link to the same thing, I wanna see if it can be done in the same tag.

```css
ul {
  width: 150px;
  height: 300px;
  border: solid 1px #000;
}

li {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

li img {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
}

li a {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  text-decoration: none;
}

li span {
  margin: 0 8px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="https://placeholder.com">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150"> <span> Username  </span>
    </a>

    <p> added you as a friend</p>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: It is not clear what your intended outcome needs to be - which text do you want to wrap?

Comment: Is it not wrapped already? Or is it overflowing outside the container?

Answer (score 2):

```css
ul {
  width: 150px;
  height: 300px;
  border: solid 1px #000;
  padding: 5px;
}

li {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

li img {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
}

li a {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  text-decoration: none;
}

li span {
  margin: 0 8px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="https://placeholder.com">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150"> <span> Username  </span>
    </a>

    <p> added you as a friend</p>
  </li>
  
</ul>
```

Maybe the `flex-wrap` property would be useful in your case. Check this link for more information
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-wrap