# Wrapping of elements instead of text in a flexbox setup

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Consider the following reproducible toy example:

```css
.foo-box { 
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: rgb(250, 250, 251);
}

#foo1 {
  display: flex;
  width: 50%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  justify-content: left;
}

#foo2 {
  display: flex;
  width: 50%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  justify-content: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="foo-box">
    <p id="foo1">This is the left hand side of the box</p>
    <p id="foo2">And this is the right hand side.</p>
</div>
```

When I resize the browser window, the text wraps in both `p` elements, as expected.

Is it possible to also make the `p` elements wrap? That is put `foo2` below `foo1`?

I have consulted a few questions on here such as:

- [Wrapping elements with flexbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51584770/wrapping-elements-with-flexbox)
- [wrapping text in flexbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50854157/wrapping-text-in-flexbox)

However, these do not seem to answer my question in a flexbox context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `flex-wrap: wrap`, it will wrap the container you have it on and you can use `flex: 1 1 auto` to set the widths of each child of the container.

```css
.foo-box {
  display: flex;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: rgb(250, 250, 251);
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

#foo1 {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  justify-content: left;
}

#foo2 {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  justify-content: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="foo-box">
  <p id="foo1">This is the left hand side of the box</p>
  <p id="foo2">And this is the right hand side.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The following solution (based on the helpful comments of @TemaniAfif and
@hungerstar) also works:

```css
.foo-box { 
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: space-between;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: rgb(250, 250, 251);
}

#foo1 {
  display: flex;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  justify-content: left;
}

#foo2 {
  display: flex;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  justify-content: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="foo-box">
    <p id="foo1">This is the left hand side of the box</p>
    <p id="foo2">And this is the right hand side.</p>
</div>
```